# ssh X11 forwarding won't work

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have been trying to get X11 port forwarding to work from my laptop.  I can't figure out why it won't work.

I get this message when I try to run xterm:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

I don't know if this is related or not, but when I login, I get this message:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/sphillips/.Xauthority
```

I have wondered if the problem is that my local user on my laptop is skp and the username on this server is sphillips.  I have been able to get X11 forwarding to work with my other computers that use the same skp login.

Also, the X11 port forwarding works from a Windows machine using Xming and Putty to the same server.  I have to manually configure the DISPLAY variable to the IP address and display 0.0, but it works.

I have run an xhost + on my machine with the attempt to try to bypass any security issues.  That still didn't work.

On the server, I check the configuration:

```
$ sudo grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#   X11Forwarding no
```

And on my machine as well:

```
$ sudo grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[sudo] password for skp: 
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#   X11Forwarding no
```

My server is RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 and my laptop is Fedora 15.

Can anyone give me any thoughts on things to try to get SSH X11 forwarding to work from my laptop?

Comment: I got the tumbleweed badge for this!  Is that a bad thing or a good thing?  I just wish someone had some thoughts on what else I could try.

Answer (score 13):

I finally found the answer (at least for my situation)!  The problem was SELinux.  I turned off SELinux, and it worked with no problem.

If you interested in all of the gory details, you can read about it on [my blog](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2012/03/23/troubleshooting-ssh-connections-and-using-syslog/), but let me detail the pertinent facts here...

On the remote machine, I used dmesg to view the logging messages:

```
dmesg | tail
```

I found a number of messages like this:

```
type=1400 audit(1332520527.110:51337): avc: denied { read } for pid=25240 comm="sshd" name="authorized_keys" dev=dm-5 ino=167 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 tclass=file
```

You can check the status of SELinux with this command:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status: enabled
SELinuxfs mount: /selinux
Current mode: permissive
Mode from config file: permissive
Policy version: 24
Policy from config file: targeted
```

You can turn it to permissive mode with this command:

```
setenforce 0
```

For more information on SELinux, I found [Red Hat's guide helpful](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html).  Also, for other SSH issues, I found [David's blog](http://dissectionbydavid.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/ssh-log-file-making-one-new-location/) helpful for getting logging to help.

For me, after that, my X11 forwarding started working with no problem.

SELinux was preventing several other different things.  It could not create the necessary files to make key authentication work.  I also found it blocking ssh-keygen from creating keys in the home directory.

Answer (score 3):

I bumped into this, too. But in my case it was because I removed IPv6 support some days ago. I then bumped into [this thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=270333) explaining how to make sure sshd uses IPv4 only.

This is how I did it, add this:

```
AddressFamily inet
```

to your ssh_config-file (on Ubuntu /etc/ssh/sshd_config) and make sshd reload its configuration (kill -SIGHUP pid-of-sshd).

Comment: Also the Google Compute Engine's latest Ubuntu boot disk image needs this line when trying to ssh with Putty!  I spent one workingday figuring this out.
http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php

Comment: You can test this with `ssh` cli args `-o "AddressFamily inet"`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue on a Debian OpenVZ container and the problem seemed to come from my /etc/hosts file where "localhost" was affected to the LAN IP, not 127.0.0.1.

Before :

```
192.168.0.15  dagi dagi.domain.net localhost localhost.localdomain
```

After :

```
192.168.0.15  dagi dagi.domain.net
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
```

After that, both `ssh -X` and `ssh -Y` worked like a charm without even restarting sshd.

Comment: Thanks Chi -- that is a good tip.  I do have that problem.  My /etc/hosts on my laptop points the host to 127.0.0.1.  But, I changed it and it still didn't make a different.  I actually tried all 3 IP addresses.  I tried the hard wired IP, the wireless IP, and the VPN (tun0-00).  I still get the same results.

Comment: Thnks Chi -- this just saved me alot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Chl s answer above, I also had a corrupt ~/.Xauthority file.

For some reason it was owned by root even under my home directory.  So I had to `sudo -s` and then deleted it.

Then recreated it with `touch ~/.Xauthority`

After that X forwarding worked for me, under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Similarly, I just didn't *have* a `~/.Xauthority` file, and creating it (empty) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config

X11Forwarding yes 
#sestatus
SELinux status: enabled
SELinuxfs mount: /selinux
Current mode: permissive
Mode from config file: permissive
Policy version: 24
Policy from config file: targeted
#You can turn it to permissive mode with this command:
#setenforce 0
```