# CentOS x11 Forwarding issue

Tags: centos, x11, putty, x11-forwarding, xming

I am on a Windows7 machine and I'm trying to get graphic view on the centOS machine to be displayed on my current screen. When typing xclock, gedit... in terminal, I am getting the following error

```
-bash: xclock: command not found
```

and This the result of **# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config** command

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#tewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Also Xming is running on **server:0.0** and I turned X11 forwarding on on putty

So what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-apps
```

Should cover it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an .Xauthority file in your home directory?

I've recently found the answer for my issue, which might be similar to yours. I've seen quite a few open questions about this topic without resolution.  You may have a few more things to work through, but SELinux settings ended up being my final hurdle.  This among many other steps are covered here: [ssh X11 forwarding won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154963/ssh-x11-forwarding-wont-work)

That aside, you may need to change the Xming settings to match the default DisplayOffset of 10 for Centos.  And after any changes to sshd_config, you'll need to restart the service via

> /etc/init.d/sshd restart

I would like to emphasize that my situation is a non-critical operation within a (hopefully!) securely-managed intranet.  I would NOT suggest turning off SELinux at work, or at home if you're hoping to open ports or configure VPN for your home network. Please consider: http://securityblog.org/2006/05/21/software-not-working-disable-selinux/