# What is the FULL TUTORIAL to set up X11 forwarding with the last CentOS CLEAN install?

Tags: ssh, centos6, x11-forwarding

Is anyone can give to me the FULL process to set up X11 forwarding from a CentOS fresh and clean install on a dedicated server ?
So, i have access to the server **only by ssh**

The problem is simple : i already tried i think all solution i find in google to make X11 forwarding working :

set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

X11Forwarding yes

and

X11UseLocalhost no or X11UseLocalhost yes

and

XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth (and xauth is in this path)

and

AddressFamily inet or AddressFamily any

restarting sshd after each write with /etc/init.d/sshd restart (and it tell to me it stop and start)

i tried to install many and many things (restarting sshd after each install) like :

yum groupinstall 'X Window System' (it works well)

xorg-x11-utils (it works)

xorg-x11-fonts-* (it works)

xorg-x11-xauth (already installed)

yum install xorg-x11-xauth.x86_64 (it works)

when i try "strings /usr/sbin/sshd |grep xauth" i got :

```
/usr/bin/xauth
xauthlocation
maxauthtries
No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
```

but /usr/bin/xauth give me :

```
Using authority file /root/.Xauthority
xauth>
```

so xauth is in the right place...

i tried all ssh option -X, -x, -Y -XY.... nothing worked.

i tried to set display myself, but nothing worked :

DISPLAY is not set, Can't open display and other errors like that.

And just after ssh login $DISPLAY is empty, always.

And i'm not sure that i have not forget some solution i have already tried...

Anyone to help me to get X11 forwarding working ?

I have
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
and my hoster is OVH

PS : sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue, due to an ~/.Xauthority file not being generated for new users upon connecting via ssh.  I'd made all appropriate changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config and reset the service via

> /etc/init.d/sshd restart

But I never had any luck until I changed my SELinux settings after finding this -  [ssh X11 forwarding won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154963/ssh-x11-forwarding-wont-work)

Of course, you only want to implement changes to SELinux if it's acceptable for your use case.  But for me, setting SELinux to permissive with

> setenforce 0

and setting the following in /etc/selinux/config - so that this change persisted after reboot

> SELINUX=permissive

I would like to emphasize that my situation is a non-critical operation within a (hopefully!) securely-managed intranet.  I would NOT suggest turning off SELinux at work, or at home if you're hoping to open ports or configure VPN for your home network. Please consider: http://securityblog.org/2006/05/21/software-not-working-disable-selinux/